# UITableView and disappearing rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an UITableView, quite standard, with quite dynamic datasource (messages).

To add messages to UITableView I'm using `insertRows`.

```
func insertRowsInTableAtIndexPath(ip: IndexPath, right: Bool) {

    print("INSERT ROW visible cells: \(tableView.visibleCells.count)\n dispatcher messages \(dispatcher.messages.count)\n numberOfRows \(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))\n numberOfSections \(tableView.numberOfSections)\n ip: \(ip.row) \(ip.section)")

    if tableView != nil {
        if right == true {
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [ip], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.right)  
        } else {
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [ip], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.left)
        }
    }

    print("AFTER INSERT ROW visible cells: \(tableView.visibleCells.count)\n dispatcher messages \(dispatcher.messages.count)\n numberOfRows \(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))\n numberOfSections \(tableView.numberOfSections)\n ip: \(ip.row) \(ip.section)")

}
```

It looks pretty standard, because it is. The problem is that in some rare cases (I can replay them but it'd be quite difficult to describe them here) I'm getting the famous `NSInternalInconsistencyException`: *Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0)* and so on.

In these cases the first message is successfully added to the `dataSource`, and it looks like this message also is inserted as row as well, but it **doesn't show up on screen**, and the next message is breaking my `UITableView` because it is invalide update (and it is).

I know that this is happening because of all of these print commands before and after inserting the cell. In bad case these numbers looks like that:

Before inserting the first message:

```
visible cells: 0
number of messages in dataSource: 1
numberOfRows: 0
numberOfSections: 1
ip: 0 0 (indexPath.row, indexPath.section)
```

After inserting the first message:

```
visible cells: 1
number of messages in dataSource: 1
numberOfRows: 1
numberOfSections: 1
ip: 0 0 (indexPath.row, indexPath.section)
```

At this point I can't see that cell (that was successfully inserted if I could believe `UITableView.visibleCells.count`)

But if I'm trying to insert the next message, I'm getting an exception. Moreover: `UITableView.visibleCells.count` is suddenly 0, and `numberOfRows` is 0 too, although I didn't remove previous row and I didn't remove this message from `dataSource`.

```
visible cells: 0
dispatcher messages 2
numberOfRows 0
numberOfSections 1
ip: 0 0
```

So, I have three questions:

1. Is it possible for UITableView to not to insert row with `insertRows`, and how could I prevent this behavior. Why the first row is not showing in the first place?
2. Why this first row is disappearing from `numberOfRows` and `visibleCells` after a while?
3. What am I doing wrong here?

I understand that this amount of code is not enough to solve this issue from scratch, but this `UITableView` is pretty standard, and dataSource logic is not so standard and relatively complicated, so my only hope is for people who already have experienced something like that.

**update (dataSource methods)**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dispatcher.messages.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

update 2 (the most relevant part of the code):

```
//this should work when user is changing from one 'chat' to another
//so, first of all, I'm removing all the messages from the dataSource
dispatcher.messages.removeAll()
//also, I'm stopping the timer
if timer != nil {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
//also, I'm reloading the table with no messages
if tableView != nil {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

//after that I'm starting the timer again, and trying to add new messages to the UITableView. The first message is going through (although it is not shown in the UITableView as it should be), the second message is throwing an error because the first row doesn't exist at this point).

let newMessage = dispatcher.giveMeNewMessage()
    if newMessage != nil {
        dispatcher.messages.insert(newMessage!, at: 0)
            let ip = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            insertRowsInTableAtIndexPath(ip: ip, right: false)
            self.scrollToRow(ip: ip) //standard scrollToRow
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your tableView dataSource methods?

Comment: yes, updated the question.

Comment: It looks fine. Can you show more context regarding how you update it? The code which has the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and where it is called? And where this method is called? Because the problem is not with the code you shared. It's in how it is used.

Comment: updated the question again.

Comment: In the error, how rows does it say has been inserted? Also you should add more code before and after than what you have just added as "*most relevant part of the code"*

Comment: Maybe, I don't understand your question but the error message: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: It seems that you are adding more than one message to `dispatcher.messages` before insert is called once. Can't tell without more code. More specifically, the code that appears before the one that you added as update 2. Also, you can refactor that with and `if let`.

Comment: Why is `tableView` optional? It's highly recommended to declare UI elements designed in IB as non-optional. And `if tableView != nil { tableView!.doSomething() } ` is very *objective-c-ish*. In Swift use conditional chaining: `tableView?.doSomething()`

Comment: @lithium can you show the `giveNewMessage()` method.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri thanks, you've saved me (I don't know why is that, but the problem was in notifications — the needed notification in some cases got there twice, so I had two timers, two cycles with inserting cells and so on. Thank you very much.

Comment: @lithium good job. (Y) :)

Comment: @vadian I'm not using IB, this tableView was created programmatically to be shown only if there is data to be shown. My coding style is not the best (to say the least), and I'd appreciate any help with links on documents describing the best practices.